# TKinter: Moving a grid in the center

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

[image]

I am trying to move this grid that is in the frame in the center. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
class Inventory:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Inventory System")
        self.root.geometry("1350x800+0+0")
        self.root.configure(background='black')

        #===================================Frames==================================================================================
        
        MainFrame = Frame(self.root ,bd=30, width=1050, height=700, bg="black", relief=RIDGE)
        MainFrame.grid()

        LeftFrame = Frame(MainFrame ,bd=10, width =1050, height=600, padx=10,bg="grey", relief=RIDGE)
        LeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: The image and the code seem completely unrelated.

Comment: if You want something in the center use `.pack()` because `grid()` isn't the best option for that, I guess it is also possible to use `place()` and `relx` and `rely`

Comment: if you want to center with grid then you would need colum on left and right and rows below and above and set weight=1 for these rows/columns.

Comment: it seems you rather want to center element added by `pack()` not `grid()`

Comment: @Matiiss: it's actually quite easy to center things with `grid` -- it's really no better nor worse than `pack`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center with `grid` then you would need colum on left and right and rows below and above and set `weight=1` for these rows/columns.

And then these rows/columns will use all free space in window and this will move frame to center. But my frame is without `width` and `height` and then all content (`Label`) looks like centered.

I added `padx=5, pady=5` only to show that this frame has black background.

If you set `root['bg'] = 'black'` then you will have all background in black.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root['bg'] = 'green'

f  = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
f.grid(row=1, column=1)

l = tk.Label(f, text='Hello World', bg='grey')
l.pack(padx=5, pady=5) #, side='left')

b = tk.Button(f, text='Exit', bg='grey', command=root.destroy)
b.pack(padx=5, pady=5) #, side='left')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # column on left
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)  # column on right
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     # row above
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)     # row below

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use `weight=1` for column/row with `Frame` and cell will use full window and frame will be centered in this cell.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root['bg'] = 'green'

f  = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
f.grid(row=0, column=0)

l = tk.Label(f, text='Hello World', bg='grey')
l.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

b = tk.Button(f, text='Exit', bg='grey', command=root.destroy)
b.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # column with Frame
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     # row with Frame

root.mainloop()
```